# Why does the following macro expect a semi-colon when called?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to write a macro to switch between rayon's `par_iter` and std's `iter` depending on a build feature (possibly getting ahead of myself, as I've not read a lot on macros yet). A macro seems a bit better to deal with than a function here, since a function might need some relatively complex types to make this work; as well a macro might remain more flexible in the future if I wanted to add even more variations in build features pertaining to how to run iterators.

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! par_iter {
    ($($tokens:tt)*) => {
      #[cfg(feature = "threaded")]
      $($tokens)*.par_iter()
      #[cfg(not(feature = "threaded"))]
      $($tokens)*.iter()
    }
}
```

I see the following error:

```
error: macro expansion ignores token `b_slice` and any following
   --> src/util.rs:28:8                                                                      
    | 
28  |       $($tokens)*.iter();
    |        ^^^^^^^^^
    |                                                                                        
   ::: src/counting.rs:219:9                                                                 
    |
219 |         par_iter!(b_slice).map(WordCount::from)                                                                                                                                     
    |         ------------------- help: you might be missing a semicolon here: `;`
    |         |                                                                              
    |         caused by the macro expansion here
    |
    = note: the usage of `par_iter!` is likely invalid in expression context
```

While I have no idea about the first error, I'm curious why a `;` is expected - how do I make it valid in expression context?

Comment: I assume you didn't mean to comment out `#[cfg(not(feature = "threaded"))]`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that was a mistake from experimentation. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This essentially boils down to, that you aren't allowed to have [attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html) within expressions like that, e.g. that the following is invalid:

```rust
b_slice.iter()
    #[cfg(not(feature = "threaded"))]
    .map(|x| x)
    .collect();
```

To fix the issue, you can assign them to a temporary variable, like this:

Note the double `{{` and `}}`, which results in a [block](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html), such that the final expression is the value that block results in.

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! par_iter {
    ($($tokens:tt)*) => {{
        #[cfg(feature = "threaded")]
        let it = $($tokens)*.par_iter();
        #[cfg(not(feature = "threaded"))]
        let it = $($tokens)*.iter();
        it
    }};
}
```

Alternatively, you can also split it into two macros like this:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "threaded")]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! par_iter {
    ($($tokens:tt)*) => {
        $($tokens)*.par_iter()
    }
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "threaded"))]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! par_iter {
    ($($tokens:tt)*) => {
        $($tokens)*.iter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd tried the first but I only had a single `{` instead of the double `{{`! I guess this makes sense as the outer `{` must only live in the macro.

Comment: Exactly, with double `{{` you wrapping everything in a block, and then the final `it` is the result of the block. (I've updated the answer to point that out, for future readers.)